# Changing the Location of Solution Items in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, location, mstest, solution

I am using VS2010 Ultimate on Windows server 2008, running 1000 odd MSTest unit tests. The .testsettings file that the solution uses to configure data collection (code coverage, impact analysis, etc) is a Solution Item, and saved where the .sln file is saved. Is it possible to change the location of the file and still have it recognized as the .testsettings file to be used in my solution... and if so, how do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you remove the testsettings file from the solution, move the file to the desired location, and then right click solution in Visual studio and select "Add existing item" and then re-add your testsettings file from the new location, all should be well.

Comment: That was almost it. I did as you suggested but VS kept recreating the test settings file in the old undesired location. I had to edit the .sln (or .vbproj) file, find where the IDE was referencing the new location, and update all other references to the old location to the new, and Bob's your uncle!